# How to get Oracle next sequence value in liqiibase 1.9.5 for insert

Tags: oracle, liquibase

How to get Oracle next sequence value in liqiibase 1.9.5 for insert

```
 <changeSet author="MIGRATE" id="070214010049877">      
  <insert tableName="MYTABLE">
    <column name="ID" valueNumeric=" nextval( 'MYTABLE_SEQ' ) "/>
    <column name="NUMBER" value="5"/>        
  </insert>
 </changeSet>
```

it is trying to put the value of **ID**  " **nextval( 'MYTABLE_SEQ' )**" in table so it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Liquibase 1.9.5, there is no support for finding the next sequence value with the `<insert>` tag. You will have to either drop back to using `<sql>` or use `<modifySql>` assuming that existed in 1.9.5.